# Will Unity be considered as interface for Kubuntu?

Tags: unity, kubuntu

I'm hearing as how Unity is using nux (and not gtk) for its gui.

I realise that it's tangled up with Compiz somehow, but I wonder if anyone has considered Unity as the future interface for Kubuntu...

So, is it technically feasible and has it been considered?

Comment: I think Unity should become an interface for KDE... Unity is much better interface for netbooks than netbook interface of KDE... it have too much funcionality, also you wouldn't install gnome libraries, because, for me, KDE applications are better than gnome (only my opinion).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Kubuntu team has a wide degree of freedom in how they structure Kubuntu - which apps they include and how they configure it by default. I doubt they will embrace Unity immediately, unless it proves extremely popular amongst Kubuntu users.

That said, we have done a lot of work to ensure that many key aspects of the interface and API's work across both GNOME and KDE. Menu's, indicators, notifications and lots of other goodness have been built for both GTK and Qt apps and are tested across both Ubuntu and Kubuntu. So Unity should work very nicely as the shell for Kubuntu if you want that yourself or if the Kubuntu folks decide to go that route.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. If you don't like KDE interface, just use Ubuntu with Unity and install the KDE applications you like. Personally, I don't even know why that should be considered? I haven't tested Unity yet, but it looks like an improved Gnome-Shell, which was the main reason I switched to KDE. Besides, Unity is an Ubuntu project and Kubuntu is mostly maintained by the community.

If they change Kubuntu so much in order to use Unity I would probably move to a different distro.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think Kubuntu should embrace Unity, but it should customize the tools KDE uses to look somewhat like Unity. bar on the left (unless using RTL language.. and then on the right), notification area on top, and so forth..